# 400 Bad Request when mapping between JSON to POJOs using Jackson JSON Mapper

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a JSON format of

```
var array1 = new Array;
var array2 = new Array;
//push some string to array1 and array2
var data = JSON.stringify({'email':email,'age':age,'array1':array1,'array2':array2});
```

How could I map it to POJOs using Jackson JSON Mapper to avoid 400 Bad Request.

I have tried

```
public class MyPOJOs{
  private String email;
  private String age;
  private MyList array1;
  private MyList array2;
  //getters and setters
}
public class MyList{
  private ArrayList  list;
  //getter and setter
}
```

My controller

```
public @ResponseBody Response myController(@RequestBody MyPOJOs myPOJOs){
   String email = myPOJOs.getEmail();
   logger.log("Hi " + email);
   return null;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: JSON requires using double quotes, not single.

Comment: JSON.stringify is to convert JavaScript values to JSON, single quote is valid in JavaScript values, so I do not think the quotes matters in this case.

Comment: Please add an actual example of the JSON string in `data` to your question. Also, how does it not work? Are there any exceptions? If so add them to your question in full.

Comment: Thanks, Philipp. The problem is sovled after defining "private ArrayList <String> array1; private ArrayList <String> array2;" in MyPOJOs class. The actual JSON data is very large,so I can not put them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really know Jackson JSON processor but I would be surprised that it is able to map your arrays to your custom `MyList` objects.

I would expect the `MyPOJOs` class to have member like `private String[] array1` or `private List<String> array1` or a `Collection`.

btw: There are many mistakes in your code that make me think you do not post real code here. Misspelled type names etc.

Comment: The problem is solved after defining "private ArrayList <String> array1;" in MyPOJOs class. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they are not real code. Edited to fix some misspelled names, and JavaScript Array object declaration.